# Ecology and evolutionary methods proposal

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Just spotted [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/100847) on Area 51. Any thoughts? It sounds like it would overlap pretty substantially with Biology.SE.

Comment: I think we cover these things pretty well over here. Ecology and evolution questions are the most popular ones here.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree. Put another way, what questions would be left behind for Biology.SE if this was accepted? Their stated target audience is "ecologists, evolutionary biologists, bioinformaticians, taxonomists, palaeobiologists, palaeontologists, conservation biologists, ecoinformaticians".

Comment: As another note, one example question for the new proposal ("Where can I get trait data for mammals?") is quite close to my (only) question on Biology.SE (http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48692/how-to-define-a-trait-objectively) - although this question hasn't really received enough attention.

Comment: As ar as I see, this proposal has been closed already as a duplicate of our site.

Comment: It has; I suspect that might have happened because I attached this question to it: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/24034/wouldnt-this-proposal-mostly-overlap-with-biology-se

Comment: @arboviral Fine :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this Area51 proposal has been closed already as a duplicate of our site.

Comment: Doesn't that mean the 'status-completed' tag is more appropriate? It's as on-topic as it ever was, and looking at previous use of that tag, completed questions are not routinely closed. This could be helpful if someone intends to propose a new biology-related SE in the future.